# How to automate x[i]→x_{i}?

Tags: latex

I have several Mathematica expressions in which subscripts are expressed with square brackets.  E.g. `x[12]` is meant to represent *x*<sub>12</sub>, etc.  If I evaluate `TeXForm` on such an expression, `x[12]`, e.g., gets converted to `x(12)`.  Is there a way to get it to produce the `x_{12}` form instead?

Comment: The problem is then telling apart `x[2]` which is meant to be $x_2$ and `f[x]` or `f[0]` which are $f(x)$ or $f(0)$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution here is to use

```
Format[x[arg_],TraditionalForm]:=Subscript[x, arg]
```

This makes sure that the subscript form is used when the display is in `TraditionalForm`, which is also an intermediate step in creating `TeXForm`. Then you get for example

```
1+x[13]//TeXForm
```

> $x_{13}+1$

The `Format` can't be specified directly for `TeXForm` because then expressions where your `x[12]` is surrounded by other things as in `1 + x[12]` won't get translated correctly.

Comment: Your answer suggests that Mathematica itself can *render* TeX.  Can it?

Comment: To a certain extent you can render $\LaTeX$, but it's very incomplete. The general idea is to use something like `TraditionalForm@ToExpression["\\sin\\alpha", TeXForm, HoldForm]`. I discussed this in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15891/245)

Comment: I just realized you may be looking for something simpler: when we say "render" $\LaTeX$, it could also mean to produce traditional-looking formulas from *Mathematica* standard form input. That is simply done by wrapping any such input in `TraditionalForm[ ...]`. You could say `TraditionalForm` is *Mathematica*'s "pretty-print formula" typesetting mode.