# Optimise CPU-intensive list combining function

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have a list of numbers `list1` from which I want to create another list (`list2`) consisting of only those numbers that are equal to the sum of *any* two members of `list1`, as long as the total is under 15.

So for example if `list1 = {1,4,6,8}`, then I want `list2 = {2,5,7,8,9,10,12,14}`.

I could do this by:

`list2 = Union[Flatten[Table[Table[i + j, {i, list1}], {j, list1}]]]`

which does give the right result, but then I run into two problems:

1. I have no idea how to filter the list so that it only displays numbers less than 15. I tried appending `/; x_ < 15` to the end, but this didn't do anything
2. This works fine for a list this small, but what I really want to do is scale this up to a list consisting of several thousand elements - for which it takes a very long time, and crashes my computer in the process. How could I make this function more efficient?

Thank you

Comment: Hmm... looks like there'll be a combinatorial explosion (even more so since you allow repetition). Why do you want to do this? Perhaps there's a better way to get to the result than brute-forcing...

Comment: Duplicate: [Memory efficient generation and selection of tuples](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28214)

Comment: Deleted my answer, pending possible duplicate status, and clarification of *what* and *why* you're doing this: as rm-rf says, there may well be a much smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way that avoids storing all the tuples.  Save whether a sum has been found in an array (`0` if no,`1` if yes).

```
SeedRandom[1];
total = 100000;
list1 = Sort@RandomInteger[{1, total}, 1000];
results = ConstantArray[0, total];

Scan[Function[x, results[[Select[x + list1, # <= total &]]] = 1], 
  list1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
   {0.614213, Null}
*)

Pick[Range@total, results, 1] // Length
(*
   80070 
*)
```

---

For speed, a compiled position-finder.  (`TakeWhile` was not fast.)

```
pos = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}, {limit, _Integer}},
   Module[{last = Length@list},
    Do[If[list[[i]] > limit, Return[last = i - 1]], {i, 
      Length@list}];
    Return[last]
    ],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

Scan[Function[x, 
   results[[x + Take[list1, pos[list1, total - x]]]] = 1], 
  list1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
   {0.035715, Null}
*)

Pick[Range@total, results, 1] // Length
(*
   80070
*)
```

Comment: Nice use of `Part`. Smart. +1