# An alternative to subscripts?

Tags: variable, index, subscript

Are there any good alternatives to using subscripts to keep track of and uniquely identify many variables? I know that subscripted variables behave badly.

Thanks!

Comment: `x[1], x[2], …`

Comment: Thank you! If you want, you can put that down in the answers and I'll up vote and check this as answered if you want the rep.

Comment: It's one of a number of methods, I think. If you got what I meant, you can answer your question yourself; I'll even upvote. :)

Comment: Some related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17693/, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36886/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to subscripts as indices...

**Instead of:**

`{Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}`

**Let's use:**

`x[1], x[2]`

**And this can be generalized to:**

`Subscript[x, i, j]` --> `x[i,j]`

This will uniquely identify any number of variables to any dimension.