# Is there a way to use a subscript as variable?

Tags: variable-definitions, subscript

I'm really new with Mathematica, and I could not find a previously question similar to this one.

Is there a way that Mathematica can be made to recognize and treat a subscript letter as variable so that I could write equations like:

$\qquad a_{n} = n + 1 $

and have the evaluation of $a_{5}$ return 6.

Note: I'm actually trying to write equation for commutators like $[L_n,\, L_m] = n - m$

Comment: You can do it now, but problems occasionally occur.  Consider, for instance, `a[n]` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica)  Also see [An alternative to subscripts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114632/142) and [Basic syntax issues (point #3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/142).

Comment: @WReach I'm afraid OP's question isn't a duplicate of that one. Though OP mentions "variable" in his post, according to the formula, OP is probably looking for something like `Subscript[a, n_] = n + 1`.

Comment: Such a functional assignment would require the redefinition of `Subscript` which will SURELY cause unwanted troubles elsewhere in *Mathematica* where subscripts are intended to use with no underlying definition. Modifying built-in symbols is not advised. On the other hand, you can make `a[n]` to format as a subscripted symbol that is still interpretable as `a[n]` or to whatever it evaluates due to its definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not using Subscript. One should think of Subscript as a **typographical** construct (which can be abused to use subscripting of a variable). Better is to use: `L[n]

comm[L[n_], L[m_]] := n - m


Then you can call the function like this:

comm[L[15], L[8]]
7`

Comment: Yeah, I actually got a way do use subscript as variable, but the program was 10 times slower, so I gave up and used your idea.

Thanks for answering!