# Numerical integration of multidimensional integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to compute quite a few multidimensional integrals with Bessel functions. Here is one example

```
NIntegrate[
 Subscript[r, 1] Subscript[r, 2] Subscript[r, 3]
   BesselK[0, Abs[Subscript[r, 1]]]^2 BesselK[0, 
   Abs[Subscript[r, 1] - 
     E^(I Subscript[\[Phi], 2]) Subscript[r, 2]]] BesselK[0, 
   Abs[E^(I Subscript[\[Phi], 2]) Subscript[r, 2] - 
     E^(I Subscript[\[Phi], 3]) Subscript[r, 
      3]]]^3 , {Subscript[\[Phi], 2], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {Subscript[\[Phi], 
  3], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {Subscript[r, 1], 0, \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[r, 
  2], 0, \[Infinity]}, {Subscript[r, 3], 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

So the accuracy of numerical integration is pretty bad with several of the methods I have tried. For example the standard `GlobalAdaptive` estimates an error about 15% and increasing `MaxErrorIncreases` from 2000 up to 10000 does not seem to help. I would be satisfied to get a correct answer within 1% accuracy and since I have to do many integrations of this type possibly in reasonable time.

The particular integral above in symbolic terms is (up to constants)
$$
\iiint d^2x_1 d^2x_2d^2x_3\,\, K_0(|x_1|)^2K_0(|x_1-x_2|)K_0(|x_2-x_3|)^3
$$
The two-dimensional integrals all run over all 2d space with standard polar measure $d^2x=r\,dr\,d\phi$  and due to rotational symmetry integration over one of the angles can be eliminated. $K_0(r)$ is the modified Bessel function `BesselK[0,r]`.

The integrand is everywhere positive so the integral is non-zero. Bessel function $K_0(r)$ has a logarithmic singularity at $r=0$ which is integrable in 1d and easily integrable in 2d since $d^2x K_0(r) \simeq  dr \,r\,K_0(r)$. I suspect that it is this singularity that leads to very imprecise numerical integration, but I'm not sure what I can do about it.

### **Edit 1**

I'm starting a bounty because the accuracy of the method suggested by Ulrich Neumann does not seem to be sufficient and even well under control.

```
realabs = Sqrt[#^2] & 
NIntegrate[r1 r2 r3 BesselK[0, realabs[r1]]^2 BesselK[0,Abs[r1 - E^(I \[Phi]2) r2]] BesselK[0,Abs[E^(I \[Phi]2) r2 - E^(I \[Phi]3) r3]]^3, {\[Phi]2, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r2,0, \[Infinity]},{r3, 0, \[Infinity]}
 , WorkingPrecision -> 15 , AccuracyGoal -> 5,Method -> {"AdaptiveMonteCarlo","SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{60.5697, 7.37415114501064}*)
```

On different runs the result fluctuates within about 10%. What is worse is that the exact answer computed by the method suggested by Roman is something like

```
NIntegrate[(2 \[Pi])^2 r1 r2 r3 BesselK[0, r1]^2 BesselK[0, 
   r2] BesselK[0, r3]^3, {r1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r2, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, {r3, 0, \[Infinity]}]
(* 11.5667 *)
```

which means that multidimensional numerical integration gives almost 50% error.

### **Edit 2**

I've tested suggestion by Alex Trounev on the following integral

```
g = Compile[{{r2, _Real}, {r3, _Real}, {r4, _Real}, {\[Phi]3, _Real}, \
{\[Phi]4, _Real}}, 
   2 \[Pi] Abs[r2]^4 BesselK[0, r2] BesselK[0, 
     Abs[E^(I \[Phi]3) r3]]^2 BesselK[0, 
     Abs[r2 - E^(I \[Phi]4) r4]]^2 BesselK[0, 
     Abs[E^(I \[Phi]3) r3 - E^(I \[Phi]4) r4]] r2 r3 r4, 
   Parallelization -> True];
zero = $MachineEpsilon; L = Infinity;
NIntegrate[
 g[r2, r3, r4, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4], {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi]4, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {r2, zero, Infinity}, {r3, zero, Infinity}, {r4, zero, 
  Infinity},
 Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"]
```

Although using compiled function definetely speeds up the process the result does not seem to be robust. I do not know the exact value of this integral but the Monte-Carlo methods seem to fluctuate a lot. `QuasiMonteCarlo` gives about 10% error estimate. Is there a way to nail the value down more reliably?

### **Edit 3**

So the above integral seems to be captured well by the `MonteCarlo` methods. To verify this we could run

```
NIntegrate[
 g[r2, r3, r4, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4], {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi]4, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {r2, zero, Infinity}, {r3, zero, Infinity}, {r4, zero, 
  Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}]
```

which returns `84.14` with `0.35` error estimate, within $1\%$ as requested.

Answer (score 8):

This integral can be done analytically by substitution. Set $x_1=r_1 e^{i\phi_1}$, $x_2=x_1+r_2 e^{i\phi_2}$, and $x_3=x_2+r_3 e^{i\phi_3}$. With these definitions, $|x_1|=r_1$, $|x_1-x_2|=r_2$, and $|x_2-x_3|=r_3$: the integral separates into three,

```
Integrate[(2π r1) (2π r2) (2π r3) r1^2 BesselK[0, r1]^2 BesselK[0, r2] BesselK[0, r3]^3,
          {r1, 0, ∞}, {r2, 0, ∞}, {r3, 0, ∞}]
(*    4/3 π^(7/2) MeijerG[{{0, 0}, {1/2}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, 4]    *)

% // N
(*    48.4506    *)
```

Of course it's a stretch to call this result "analytic" when it contains a Meijer G function. However, it is now reduced to a standardized function, for which there are accurate and proven algorithms and there is no need for numerically optimized integration. Further, with [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) we can find the definition of this Meijer G function in terms of logarithms and polylogarithms:

```
%% // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
(*    4/27 π^3 (Sqrt[3] π Log[4] - PolyGamma[1, 1/3] + 
      PolyGamma[1, 2/3] + 6 I Sqrt[3] (PolyLog[2, 1/4 - (I Sqrt[3])/4] - 
      PolyLog[2, 1/4 + (I Sqrt[3])/4]))    *)
```

Comment: That's right! In fact I've chosen this example because the exact solution can be found but forgot to write about it. Consider the same integral with the argument of the first Bessel function now being $K_0(|x_1-x_3|)$. The substitution trick becomes more problematic but perhaps doable. Now consider where I have say four variables $x_i$ and the number of pairwise differences $x_i-x_j$ (6)  is larger then the number of variables (4). I do not see a way to bypass the numeric integration in this case.

Comment: This is why it's important to ask about your actual question, not a substitute.

Comment: I need to compute numerous integrals of this form and this particular one I thought captured the problem. Your point is taken and your effort appreciated. I actually might reconsider my computational approach based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Roman What is the relation between the `Integrate` you give in the first codeline and the first codeline `NIntegrate`   @Weather Report asks for?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I started from the given symbolic integral. @WeatherReport's first `NIntegrate` codeline seems to miss a factor of $2\pi|x_1|^2$ in the integrand.

Comment: @Roman Thanks a lot. Your answer is very impressive for me, now trying to understand the substitution `x1,x2,x3-> r1,r2,r3` in detail.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann just consider the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation and see that it is equal to 1.

Answer (score 5):

**final modification ;-)**

Without "Subscripts" ( [avoid use of subscripts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114632/an-alternative-to-subscripts)   )

```
realabs = Sqrt[#^2] & 
NIntegrate[r1 r2 r3 BesselK[0, realabs[r1]]^2 BesselK[0,Abs[r1 - E^(I \[Phi]2) r2]] BesselK[0,Abs[E^(I \[Phi]2) r2 - E^(I \[Phi]3) r3]]^3, {\[Phi]2, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r1, 0, \[Infinity]}, {r2,0, \[Infinity]},{r3, 0, \[Infinity]}
 , WorkingPrecision -> 15 , AccuracyGoal -> 5,Method -> {"AdaptiveMonteCarlo","SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{60.5697, 7.37415114501064}*)
```

evalutes the intergal without error messages!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the latest `Mathematica` (v.11 here) and it seems that `RealAbs` is not available to me. However I do not understand (1) why do you suggest to use `RealAbs` on a complex-valued expressions? (2) How can the integral be zero given that the integrand is strictly positive?

Comment: @WeatherReport `RealAbs` was introduced , because `Abs` sometimes shows problems with `NDSolve, NIntegrate,...`.  The parameters `r1,r2,r3 ` are real, that's why `RealAbs` is   permitted. Try as a workaround `realabs= Sqrt[#^2]&`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. I use genuinely complex coordinates to parametrize 2d plane so your suggestion should not work directly. I have tried to use `realabs[z_] := Sqrt[Re[z Conjugate[z]]]` without any change. It is very suspicious to me that you get zero (the expression in integral is positive!) and that exact integration can compute anything at all in this case.

Comment: @WeatherReport See the modification in my answer, hopefully that's the solution you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work better! However as far as I can tell the accuracy goal is far from reached. On three different runs I've got `7.07916951265200`, `6.38668393270717` and `7.50130413248911`. I actually have an impression that Monte-Carlo methods do not care too much about the accuracy goals:)

Comment: I just briefly looked at this thread but I've worked a bit with achieving high numerical accuracy with NIntegate.   What I found is that as long as you can provide a sufficient working precision, you can dramatically reduce the step size to improve the accuracy but more time.  I recall doing one with a Precision goal of 110 and step size of 1/40000.  Took 4 hours to integrate but yielded the desired result.  Maybe look into this.

Answer (score 5):

We can try to use compiled function, then we have

```
f = Compile[{{r1, _Real}, {r2, _Real}, {r3, _Real}, {p2, _Real}, {p3, \
_Real}}, r1 r2 r3 BesselK[0, r1]^2 BesselK[0, 
    Abs[r1 - E^(I p2) r2]] BesselK[0, 
     Abs[E^(I p2) r2 - E^(I p3) r3]]^3, Parallelization -> True];
zero = $MachineEpsilon; L = Infinity; 
NIntegrate[
   f[r1, r2, r3, p2, p3], {r1, zero, L}, {r2, zero, L}, {r3, zero, 
    L}, {p2, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {p3, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo"] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming
{1.34761, 11.3053}
```

It is much quicker than other options and also close to the `exact solution`. Another method even faster but it fluctuates much

```
NIntegrate[
   f[r1, r2, r3, p2, p3], {r1, zero, L}, {r2, zero, L}, {r3, zero, 
    L}, {p2, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {p3, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "MonteCarlo"] //
   Quiet // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {1.24183, 11.4401}*)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I've tested it on another example and unfortunately it does not perform as well. I'll update the question.

Comment: @WeatherReport It could be better you show all integrals you try to calculate. There is no general algorithm for any case, but we can do something  in every particular case.

Comment: So your approach with the compiled functions turned out to be very helpful. Then it turns out I don't even have to use the `MonteCarlo` methods and standard `GlobalAdaptive` works fine and more reliably. Another thing that helped me is a realization that I do not have to consider all integrals  one-by-one (I need only their sum) but instead compute only the total integral. So now I do not need to optimize every piece separately. All answers in this thread are very helpful, but yours nailed down my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @WeatherReport You are welcome!