# How to fix the spacing problem using TeXForm for styling plots

Tags: latex

Reference my old questions, *[How to use LaTeX for typesetting labels and titles in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15884)* and *[LaTeX and Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736)*.

The problem is simple to explain. When I do this

```
p = Plot[0, {x, 0, 2},
  Epilog -> Text[
    Style[ToExpression["\\sin(x\\,y)", TeXForm, HoldForm], Large], {1, .5}]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The spacing between `x` and `y` is too large. Is there a way to reduce it?

I am using version 10.0.2 on Windows.

Comment: I normally use an invisible space for typesetting things such as `(x y)`. Can't help you with the second part. LaTeX fonts always look different to everything else IMO

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch adding invisible space does not work for TeXForm, it still appears as one letter `xy`. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uXsHj.png) which is the issue mentioned above by Jens about the spacing.

Comment: Does the option `ZeroWidthTimes->True` help with the first issue? I.e., `Text[Style[ToExpression["\\sin(x\\,y)", TeXForm, HoldForm], Large, ZeroWidthTimes -> True], {1, .5}]`

Comment: @kguler that is a nice trick. Yes, it helped a lot. Now the spacing is OK and can live with it. I'll update my question with your suggestion so it is all in one place. I guess now only the font issue is left. I am looking to see if there is a font setting to use.

Comment: @kguler fyi, I updated the question to only for the font issue. Thanks to your hint, the spacing issue is no longer a problem.

Comment: @Nasser, glad to know that it works for version 10.0.2 too -- i had no way of checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the option `ZeroWidthTimes->True` in `Style` solves the spacing problem:

```
expr = Style[ToExpression["\\sin(x\\,y)", TeXForm, HoldForm], Large, ZeroWidthTimes -> True];

Plot[0, {x, 0, 2}, Epilog -> Text[expr, {1, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I modified my question also to mention the spacing issue only, to reduce confusion. I think your solution is very good.

Comment: @Nasser, my pleasure... thank you for the accept.