# How to make a letter bold or script-like by latex when plotting labels?

Tags: plotting, latex

I am trying to put labels that look like the following,

[image]

[image]

I use

```
Graphics[{Text[
   Style[ToExpression["a+\\bm{v}_i", TeXForm, HoldForm], 
    FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0, 0}], 
  Text[Style[ToExpression["b+\\cal{L}(\\bm{v}_i)", TeXForm, HoldForm],
     FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0, .2}]}]
```

[image]

[image]

but do not get result as expected. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: _Mathematica_ is not good at importing TeX, so instead of importing TeX, you could use boxes: e.g. `Text["a+\!\(\[ScriptV]\_i\)"]` and `Text["b+\[ScriptCapitalL](\!\(\[ScriptV]\_i\))"]`

Comment: Take a look at [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), a package for $\LaTeX$ typesetting in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Possible duplicate:[(736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/736) (specifically [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943/4999)). Related: [(15884)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15884).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
Graphics[
  {Text[
     Style[
       a + Subscript[Style[v, Bold, SingleLetterItalics -> False], i], 
       "TR", 14], 
     {0, 0}, {-1, 0}], 
   Text[
     Style[
        b + \[ScriptCapitalL][Subscript[Style[v, Bold, SingleLetterItalics -> False], i]], 
        "TR", 14], 
     {0, -.1}, {-1, 0}]}]
```

[image: result]