# Latex Matrix in PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending, latex

I would like to have the expression
$$\rho\!\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=1$$
as a legend of a plot. When I try (code is adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15891/36894))
`Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Text[Style[ToExpression["\\rho\\left({{1/(p-1),1/(p-1)},{2/(q-1),0}}\\right)=1",TeXForm, HoldForm], Bold]]}, {.4, .8}]]`

I obtain the following:
[image]
which is not what I want...

I tried using MaTex but had trouble installing it (in the configuration step)...

Is there a simple way to fix my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eqn = HoldForm[ ρ MatrixForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}}] == 1];

Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style[eqn, Bold]}, {.4, .8}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `MaTeX`

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
pl=HoldForm[p {{a,b},{c,d}}==1];
plt=MaTeX[TeXForm@pl,Magnification->1.5];
Plot[x^2,{x,0,1},PlotLegends->Placed[plt,{.4,.8}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use `rho` in place of `p`, you can try replacing the `p` (since only one of them happen to be there in this example)

```
pl=HoldForm[p {{a,b},{c,d}}==1];
plt=ToString@TeXForm@pl;
plt=MaTeX[StringReplace[plt,"p"->"\\rho"],Magnification->1.7];
Plot[x^2,{x,0,1},PlotLegends->Placed[plt,{.4,.8}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually the `ToString@TeXForm[...]` is not necessary. This is done automatically by MaTeX.  Just writing `pl` instead is sufficient.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks. I did not know this. Changed the first example. But for the second example, I still need `ToString` I think, since I needed to do `StringReplace` later on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
pl = p {{a, b}, {c, d}} == 1 // HoldForm // TraditionalForm // 
   Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 500] & // Magnify[#, 1] &;

Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Placed[pl, {.4, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good :), thank you very much. The only little details is that the "p" is not a $p$ but a rho $\rho$. Is it possible to also include that or it would make the solution much more complicated?

Comment: Instead of the "normal" p just input esc rho esc