# Greek letters appearance in graphics

Tags: graphics, labeling, style

Why does the Greek Letter "ν" with esc+n+esc turn into the English letter "v"
when used in graphics e.g. labeling a frame?
Is there any solution to this, please? Thanks!

Example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Nu]", "\[Lambda]"}]
```

Comment: Please add Mathematica code for a **minimal working example**.

Comment: Apply on example above, please

Comment: ```Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5 \[Pi]}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {StringForm["``", 
    Style[\[Nu], 14, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"]]
   , StringForm["``", 
    Style[\[Lambda], 14, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"]]}
 ]```

Comment: This works too: ```Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5 \[Pi]}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {Style[\[Nu], 14, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"]
   , Style[\[Lambda], 14, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"]}
 ]```

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Another possibility is MaTeX (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98430/4999) or [here](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) or [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall)). Once installed, execute ``Needs["MaTeX`"]`` whenever you want to use it. Then `FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\nu"], MaTeX["\\lambda"]}` gives nice TeX'ed labels.

Answer (score 5):

It is not turned into "v", it is just the way "nu" looks like in the default output font (Arial in my case). Use `Style` to use another `FontFamily`, or `TraditionalForm`.

```
Style["α β ν", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]

TraditionalForm["α β ν"]
```

[image: Greek letters]

Example for your plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"ν", "λ"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 20}]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Can you try on example above? I wonder why does it not work for "FontFamily -> "MathJax_SansSerif""

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks!